# Add "Appendix" before "A" for Appendix A

Tags: appendices, scrbook

I have the following latex document, and I want to add "Appendix" to the title of the Appendix A. So far the prefix "Appendix" only shows up in the TOC, but I also want to add the prefix "Appendix" to the title of the respective chapter.

```
\documentclass[headsepline,footinclude=false,oneside,fontsize=12pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,listof=nochaptergap]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\newpage

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Test}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

That's how the appendix appears in the TOC which is correct:
[image: TOC]

But the header in the text still looks like this:
[image: Title Header]

Is there any way I can change this behavior, so it prints "Appendix A. Test" as the title of the appendix? Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes you are right thanks for pointing this out. That solved my problem :) Thanks again!